# How to click 'follow' button on vine.co vb.net

Tags: c++, vb.net, button, click, vine

I'm trying to click on a button on vine.co on a users channel, I am using vb.net c+ a webbrowser called 'webbrowser1' and I have tried some methods but they don't seem to be working, Can someone please help me with clicking the 'follow' button on a users page on vine.co for example this link: https://vine.co/ShawnLauderback 
this is the code when I click inspect element on the follow button:

```
<button id="ember4097" class="ember-view clear follow-button-large follow"><script id="metamorph-         
1388-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
<script id="metamorph-1389-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
<script id="metamorph-1390-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
<div class="button-icon"><div class="icon-plus"></div></div>
Follow
<script id="metamorph-1390-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
<script id="metamorph-1389-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
<script id="metamorph-1388-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
</button>
```

Comment: I'd recommend using a web automation framework, for example Canopy http://lefthandedgoat.github.io/canopy/

Comment: Canopy is not working for me, plus I need a gui which I cannot do with a console application

Comment: Canopy does not require a GUI, it is however built on top of Selenium which you could hit directly instead if you prefer

Comment: What I meant was I need a GUI for my application because I want one but since you have to create a console application with canopy I cannot put a GUI

Comment: I don't think there's any reason why Canopy can't be used in a GUI app

Comment: I want to make it so that when you click a button it triggers the sequence, e.g. click a button > follows the person

Comment: sure, no problem, when the button is clicked on the application GUI you could use the web automation framework to click the web page button

Comment: Where would I put the canopy code ? on a windows form code?

Comment: I'm using visual basic btw

Comment: Canopy is an F# based DSL, you could call that from your VB.Net app, or if you prefer use Selenium directly from VB.Net